# Remove basename (last directory) from a path and store them in a file

Tags: bash, text, find

In bash, how to do it?

For eg i have a text file named FILE1 having 4 paths in it seperated by new line:

```
abc/def/zzz.txt
ghi.jkl/zzz.txt
mno.pqr/zzz.txt
stu.wvx/zzz.txt
```

I want to create another file named FILE2 from FILE1, which only includes:

```
abc/def/
ghi/jkl/
mno/pqr/
stu/wvx/
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

using `sed`:

```
sed -r  's|[^\/]+$||g' FILE1 > FILE2
```

and see regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/n3tPkn/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat FILE1)
do
    echo "${line%/*}/" >> FILE2
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    echo "${line%/*}/" >> FILE2
done < FILE1
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Khilin. :)

Comment: Can you explain what is ${line%/*}/ doing?

Comment: @Pompy ```${PARAMETER%PATTERN}``` looking for the pattern matches in the end of the string and remove it. In your case, I've removed `/*`, means `/zzz.txt`

Comment: Thanks once again. :)